# How to pass checkbox data from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to pass data from one page to another using asp.net

I wrote this code in the second page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    Div1.InnerHtml = "I am here";

    if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1 = 
            (CheckBoxList)PreviousPage.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");

        string section = "";

        foreach (ListItem sec in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (sec.Selected)
            {
                section += sec.Text + "<br />";
                this.d.InnerHtml = section;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it does not work :(

Please help me to find the error :)

Comment: Do you get any exception, or are the check boxes just not found? Also, is there any special reason for doing it this way, instead of using a session to store the data, as Andrei Neculai writes?

Comment: No I do not get any exception by using this way. I tried to use session but it also not work:(

Answer (score 2):

Save the checkbox values from the first page in session variables or cookies, from where they can be retrieved later in the second page.

Comment: I tried to use the session variables 
i saved the value of the check box in the first page
protected void checkbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["checkbox"] = list.Value;
        }
then I read this value in the second page
                String name = Session["checkbox"].ToString();
                this.d.InnerHtml = name;
but this error occured
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: When you set the session, put a break point, and check the value of list.Value.  Also, are you using Server.Transfer ?